# How to get values of env vars by writing groovy script on jenkins script console?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, environment-variables

I searched a lot for this problem but couldn't find working solution anywhere. Can anybody please help me out? I want to get already existing env vars value through jenkins script console.

Comment: You can print all the environment variables, using - sh 'printenv'

Answer (score 2):

You need to distinguish:

- [build environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26428580/6309):

  ```
  def myVar = build.getBuildVariables().get('myVar')
  ```
- [system environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47095584/6309):

  ```
  System.getenv('MY_VARIABLE')
  ```

If you see

```
 groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: manager for class: Script1
```

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26730819/6309), and define `build` first:

```
import hudson.model.*

def build = Thread.currentThread().executable
def buildNumber = build.number
```

Comment: I'm using build env vars..Writing only this in jenkins script console :                        
def myVar = build.getBuildVariables().get('BUILD_NUMBER')                                  is giving :                                                          
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: build for class: Script1 . output.

Comment: @TarishiJain OK. I have edited the answer to address that error message.

Comment: getting this error now: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: executable for class: java.lang.Thread ..Please help!

Comment: @TarishiJain Check if https://stackoverflow.com/a/38130496/6309 can help for that second error message.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47098330/how-can-i-access-jenkins-build-environment-variables-from-within-groovy-scripts), in order to access env vars from Jenkins script console, do as follows :

```
import jenkins.model.*;
import hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty;
import hudson.EnvVars;

jenkins = Jenkins.instance;
EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty prop = jenkins.getGlobalNodeProperties().get(EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty.class)
EnvVars env = prop.getEnvVars()

def myVariable = env['MY_VAR']
```

The env vars listed in `http://<JENKINS_URL>/env-vars.html` are available for each build. In order to access these variables in the Jenkins script console you need to define first the build :

```
build = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName('JOB_NAME').getBuildByNumber(BUILD_NUMBER)
envvars = build.getEnvironment()
envvars.each{envvar ->
  println envvar
}
```

Comment: It is giving null for all the build env vars.

Comment: This gives you the env vars defined globally on every nodes (EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty). What env vars do you want ? For a specific build or a specific node ? When do you want to access it ? While running a build or through the script console once the build is runned ?

Comment: I want to get the values of env vars listed here: http://<jenkins-url>/env-vars.html/   ..and want to acess them via jenkins script console (by writing groovy script in there).

Comment: I edited my answer. The env vars you want access are defined for each build, so you need first to define the build. Replace `JOB_NAME` with the name of your job and `BUILD_NUMBER` by the number of the build you want to access its env vars.